# How can i get data from a JSON request in android?

Tags: android, json

Im trying to create a currency converter app on android.
    im getting this String request from an api

```
{"base":"USD","date":"2018-07-27","rates":{"RON":3.9819354839}}
```

i'd like to somehow parse this string (using json) and get the RON value

this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button convert;
    TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        final EditText textBox1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText textBox2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button convert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(),1024*1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        requestQueue=new RequestQueue(cache,network);
        requestQueue.start();


        convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String text2= spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String URL ="https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?base="+text1+"&symbols="+text2;
                StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                textView.setText(response);
                                Log.e("Rest response", response.toString());
//                                requestQueue.stop();
                            }

                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        textView.setText("error......");
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue! Maybe this will help other people too.

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                                    JSONObject ratesObj = obj.getJSONObject("rates");
                                    String currency = ratesObj.getString(convertedValue);
```